# Why do some graphics programs use ClearType to render text in exported images?

Tags: images, cleartype, font-smoothing

Some graphics programs (for example, LibreOffice Draw running on Windows) use [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) to render text in exported raster images. This is usually not the case with more "serious" graphics software such as Photoshop or the Gnu Image Manipulation Program.

I can understand the use of ClearType while editing a document (even if I personally don't agree that it looks better than text anti-alised using only shades of the text color), but using it to render text in an exported raster file (which might be printed, edited in another program, etc.) seems quite strange, as the fringes of color associated with ClearType serve little purpose in a 300 DPI raster image that's going to be printed (for example).

Is there a reason why developers might choose to use ClearType when rendering text in raster output? Are they simply assuming that it's more likely such images will be viewed on a screen than printed out or otherwise manipulated? Is it just a shortcut to reduce development time? Either way, it seems an odd choice.

**EDIT** For reference, here's an example of text rendered with "normal" anti-aliasing (from Photoshop) compared with text rendered using ClearType (from LibreOffice Draw).

[image]

Comment: This is basically impossible to answer as we're not the creators of the programs you're thinking of.  Having said that, you may not be seeing "ClearType" specifically; "They" may just be anti-aliasing the whole image before saving, and if it happens to have text, it gets anti-aliased as well.

Comment: Maybe just because the programmer uses the default rendering engine instead of select the non-ClearType one

Comment: techie007, I'm specifically referring to ClearType anti-aliasing. I understand the rationale for anti-aliasing of text in general. I've added an image of output from two programs to clarify this. Regarding the "impossibility" of this question, I'm just looking for a convincing reason (if one exists) why ClearType would be selected over "regular" anti-aliasing. Are there users who actually prefer raster text output to be produced using ClearType rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClearType is just one type of sup-pixel antialiasing (they use different algorithms but look almost the same)

As Lưu Vĩnh Phúc commented, they are probably taking the easy path by taking a capture from the screen rendering instead of making a proper export.

There is a simple way to see if that is the case (you should test each program): look for "TrueType Text Tuner" on your system, disable it, and export a test image from LifreOffice to see if it still uses sub-pixel antialiasing.

Comment: In LibreOffice's case, turning off ClearType results in anti-aliasing using only the color of the text. However, it doesn't look nearly as nice as rasterized text produced by Photoshop or the GIMP, so it's probably still being produced via Windows. I suppose the "easy path" explanation is likely the correct one. Rather disappointing!